# Same Router IP Segment

Tags: ip, router

I was trying to configure my router by following the manual, the IP address is 192.168.1.1
To access it i have to manually give my LAN address of 192.168.1.X which says to be the same segment as the router's IP in the manual.

What i'd like to know is what does that mean? Can anyone give me some pointers as to why I have to assign such IP to the LAN first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an active router, local area networks (LAN) can only communicate within their boundary or network segment (neglecting special devices like bridges). To allow this communication inside the network, all clients need a compatible addressing system. For TCP/IP this means that all clients need to have a distinct IP adddress inside a [subnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) defined by the netmask as second parameter to the IP address.

Some network devices can be configured without the need for compatible IP addresses, they use direct ethernet communication below the IP level, but this requires special configuration software and can't be done via a web browser.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, the 192.168.1.X address is actually the range of IP for the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 shown in the router right?

Comment: Yes. Given the IP address 192.168.1.X and the netmask 255.255.255.0, this leaves the values of (1..255) for X. Note that 1 is already taken by the router.

Answer (score 1):

Two machines can only access each other directly if they are numbered inside the same network segment. You want to be able to access the router directly, so you have to assign the machine an IP address in the same network segment as the router.

Comment: same network segment  = under the same subnet?

Comment: That's exactly right.